# is there a way to sort css class names, ids, and elements in the css navigator window in visual studio 2010

Tags: asp.net, css, visual-studio-2010

How do you sort the class, element, or element id's in the css outline window?  Is this possible? I've used the NetBeans IDE recently and I noticed that feature was present by default:

[image]

Here is what I see in visual studio 2010

[image]

Comment: I've added a screenshot of my visual studio configuration (which is pretty much the default...).  I don't see what you posted below....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default configuration categorizes the classes by order:
[image]

But if you use the options and change it to categorize by type, it will alphabetize the definitions within each type.

[image]

Comment: My vs2010 config css window doesn't look like yours?  Screenshot pasted above in the original question.

Comment: Ahh, I see. I was using the Manage Styles window instead of the CSS outline toolbox that is available when directly editing a CSS document. I'll look for an alternative or solution.

Comment: Good job - this is the solution!  i can use this for what I need.  Really pays to know your IDE.  Thanks dude!

Comment: I had no idea that window existed. great!

Comment: And it pays you when i realize I have to accept the bounty.  Sorry for the delay.  I appreciate your help.